# Yii2: Validate content of a file before submitting

Tags: yii2

In my form I have a field for the user to upload an XML file. But before submitting the XML, I have to validate it. How can I create a validation function for this?

My view:

```
...
<?= $form->field($model, 'upload_file')->fileInput(['accept' => 'text/xml']) ?>
...
```

My Model:

```
...
['upload_file', 'validateFile'],
...
public function validateFile($attribute, $params)
{
// TODO
}
...
```

I can access and validate the contents of the XML file in the controller, but this validation is already after the file is submitted ... I wanted before submitting!
Exemple in controller:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) {
    $file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'upload_file');
    $file = file_get_contents($file->tempName);
    // xml of the upload_file
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($file);
```

I want to pass this code that is on top, to the validation function.

Comment: I tried to use the "validationUrl" in "ActiveForm", but it does not send files, just text.

Comment: it's can't validate on frontend site. because fileInput only html tag, if need validate, you need add some javascript code. So i suggest you using Yii2 File Input, it enhanced widget with more feature. It's here https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your model rules:

```
public function rules()
{
     return [
          [['uploaded_file'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'xml', 'mimeTypes' => 'text/xml, application/xml'],
     ];
}
```